# Is a file that can be shown by `mdimport -d2 file` in spotlight database?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have a file that can be shown with the following command.

```
$ mdimport -d2 file.pdf
```

But when I use the following command to search for the file. The file won't show up immediately.

```
mdfind -onlyin dir_the_file_is_in "(kMDItemTextContent=='searchterm'c) && (kMDItemFSName=='*.pdf')"
```

After I wait for sometime since I open it with Acrobat, then the above `mdfind` command will find it. Furthermore, I actually can not tell whether it is because I used Acrobat to open the file or because I used `mdimport -d2 file.pdf` so that the file can be found as I did both.

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Comment: Using `mdimport -d2 [file]` doesn't do anything-- it prints an error message about how the command line options are wrong. so it's hard to tell what you're doing here.

Comment: `mdimport .` takes a lot of time (1 minute for PDFs of about 600MB) to run on my Mac. If it does not perform indexing on the fly, why does it take a long time to run?

Comment: Spotlight normally does index on the fly. I've never checked too closely but 1 minute for 600MB doesn't seem unreasonable. I still don't know what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @TomHarrington The problem is my files are not necessarily found in the spotlight index. I'd like to make sure that they are always in a spotlight index.